# undefined method `association_class' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, spree, class-eval

I'm working with Spree 2.1 and trying to add new payment gateway, but this error is more generic so Spree itself is not-so-important here.

I have encountered that error (`undefined method 'association_class' for nil:NilClass`) after adding some module to `Spree::PaymentMethod` ([source](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/payment_method.rb)) class:

spree/payment_method_decorator.rb

```
Spree::PaymentMethod.class_eval do
  include Spree::Core::CalculatedAdjustments
end
```

(`Spree::Core::CalculatedAdjustments` [source](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/calculated_adjustments.rb))

(`Spree::Gateway` [source](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/gateway.rb))

Unfortunately, now `Spree::PaymentMethod` ([source](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/payment_method.rb)) breaks a little, i.e:

```
n = Spree::PaymentMethod.first
=> #<Spree::Gateway::Bogus id: 1, (...)>
n.save
=> undefined method 'association_class' for nil:NilClass
n.calculator
=> undefined method 'association_class' for nil:NilClass
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

In fact I already have an answer (after few hours of struggle), but maybe someone will give a better one with proper explanation. Maybe the answer is quite obvious, but it wasn't for me and I couldn't find anything related on SO so hopefully someone else with similar level of RoR knowledge won't have to spend another few hours on that.

Comment: What did you do to fix it? Can you answer your own question? I ran into the same problem.

Comment: @maikel sorry for late response, I had to dig in my old laptop for that project ;) I have posted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was:

As it is visible in above links, `Spree::Gateway` is inheriting from `Spree::PaymentMethod` and my custom payment method was inheriting from `Spree::Gateway` class - something like:

`module Spree
  class Gateway::CustomMethod < Gateway
  end
end`

All I had to do was to include `Spree::Core::CalculatedAdjustments` in `Spree::Gateway`:

`Spree::Gateway.class_eval do
  include Spree::Core::CalculatedAdjustments 
end`

and it is working since then.